# Session attribute in JSP template

Tags: spring, jsp

I have a session attribute which is an HashMap and representing a shopping cart.

I would like to get the HashMap size in the template to make something like "Shopping cart (4 items)" in the nav bar.

Is there a way to achieve this without adding the HashMap size in every Model of every Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `jstl` funtion along with core tag -

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

Then you can get `size` of any `map` or `list` by this -

```
<c:set var="cartMapSize" value="${fn:length(yourMap)}"/>
```

Now you can access `cartMapSize` anywhere in your page like this -

`${cartMapSize}`

In your case this would look like this -

> *Shopping cart (`${cartMapSize}` items)*